# How to catch gherkin.parser.ParseError in JUnit runner class

Tags: java, maven, junit, cucumber-jvm

I have a JUnit runner class for my cucumber tests

```html
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(plugin = {
        "html:target/results/cucumber-html-report",
        "json:target/results/cucumber.json", "" +
        "pretty:target/results/cucumber-pretty.txt",
        "usage:target/results/cucumber-usage.json",
        "junit:target/results/cucumber-results.xml"},
        tags = {"@test2"},
        features = {"src/test/resources/features/",},
        glue = {"com.xvpn.test.step"})
public class Runner {
}
```

And sometimes we might have parse error (when someone commited smth without testing)
When I launch my Junit runner itself, it throws me gherkin.parser.ParseError, which is cool and I can easily catch the problem
But when tests are launched my maven command - mvn test, it doesn't show me any errors and exceptions

The question is, show can I catch parse error in JUnit class? Or is there any way to show that exception as error of maven output?

Answer (score 0):

[Maven Surefire Plugin / Inclusions and Exclusions of Tests](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html)

> By default, the Surefire Plugin will automatically include all test
>   classes with the following wildcard patterns:
>
> ```
> "**/Test*.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that start with "Test".
> "**/*Test.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that end with "Test".
> "**/*Tests.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that end with "Tests".
> "**/*TestCase.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that end with "TestCase".
> ```

You'll have to rename your runner class to fit the pattern. It would appear that it currently is not executed at all.